# Tracking all the requests and responses of a server using node js

Tags: node.js, service, server, listener

I am beginner in nodejs app development. I have the following requirement,

A Webapp running on a server-A on a host. Another service is to be implemented and run on a different host should intercept all the incoming requests and outgoing responses from the WebApp running on a server-A. All these details has to be stored in a file.

Looking for example or thought on how to implement the intercepting service. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at socket.io, it's a socket client & server for Node.js (here is a demo: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

You can use socket.io to send the data between both apps, and then you write the data to a file using [file stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html):

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile(__dirname "/file.txt", "Hello World!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("File saved!");
});
```